# emacs open directory file information

Tags: emacs

This might be silly, but can be healthy to a lot of Emacs beginners, like myself.
when opening a directory, list of files along with many information: owner, dates , permissions are showed. These are unnecessary for developers who might care about file name and relative location. So how can we change the options in Emacs to do such thing?

Also for large project navigation. any general advice how to navigate different files in smooth way? (I can see entering folder with 'i' in order to stay in same buffer) any general advice for smoother walk?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4115699/1937596

Answer (score 0):

here what to customize and my preferred value - i.e. the last edited files at bottom of buffer:

dired-listing-switches is a variable defined in `dired.el'.
Its value is "-lart"

Comment: I don't understand what to do?

Comment: blackmath: Do C-h v dired-listing-switches and then click customize. Here you can edit the switches. See that 'l' is a MUST switch.

Comment: I want only to show the file names. no permissions or sizes or whatever. So its near to IDE when developing some project

Answer (score 0):

This removes the owner and group indicator:

```
(require 'ls-lisp)
(setq ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program nil
      ls-lisp-verbosity nil)
```

I use this because `dired-listing-switches` doesn't quite do the trick in Cygwin.

You cannot, that I'm aware of, get rid of more than that in `dired` out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanks Harpo, Is it possible to remove the permissions too? and if you can explain a little your small 3 lines for us to learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you use emacs 24.4 you can type `(` in dired to call function `dired-hide-details-mode`. Otherwise you could try [dired-details](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredDetails).